# pg-promise: use result of one query in next query within a transaction

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, pg-promise

I am node.js with pg-promise for postgres, trying to do a transaction with 2 inserts in sequence. The result id of the 1st insert should be used in the next insert in the transaction.

Rollback if any of the query fails.
Nesting 2nd `db.none` inside `.then()` of 1st `db.one` will NOT rollback 1st query. So using a transaction here.

I am stuck at using the result of 1st query in 2nd.
Here is what I have now.

```
db.tx(function (t) {
    return t.sequence([
        // generated using pgp.helpers.insert for singleData query
        t.one("INSERT INTO table(a, b) VALUES('a', 'b') RETURNING id"),
        t.none("INSERT INTO another_table(id, a_id) VALUES(1, <above_id>), (2, <above_id>)")
    ]);
})...
```

2nd query is generated using pgp.helpers.insert for multiData query. But that's not feasible wanting to use the previous query's result. isn't it !

Is there a way to get `id` i.e. `<above_id>` from the 1st INSERT ?

Comment: there should be object with t.one result. It will contain your id. wait for @vitay-t to explain :)

Comment: Why use `batch` if you want them to be run sequentially?

Comment: @pozs It was a mistake. t.sequence is what I meant. Edited the question.

Comment: @Maven What data are you seeking to get from the transaction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Method [sequence](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#sequence) is there to run infinite sequences, which got nothing to do with what you are trying to achieve - a standard / trivial transaction:

```js
await db.tx(async t => {
    const id = await t.one('INSERT INTO table1(a, b) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id', [1, 2], a => +a.id);
    await t.none('INSERT INTO table2(id, a_id) VALUES($1, $2)', [1, id]);
});
```

Comment: ok, Standard transaction is the way to go then. Now I can created the second insert query with `pgp.helpers.insert` after `.then(id => {`. Isn't it ? I will try this out.

Comment: just wanted to take the id from previous transaction and create multiData insert query pgp helper.  It worked. Thanks.

Comment: How would you do the same using `async`/`await`? Is `var id = await t.one('INSERT...` and then use `id` in the second query equivalent to a nested transaction?

Comment: @ezorita https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md

Comment: upvoted! just wanted to say you are totally awesome , anything and almost everything is either answered in your github issues or here

Comment: Updated to use `async` syntax.